Getting separate output file using refcheck.sty
I tried with
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{H1 Head}\label{h1head}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

Test for cross-ref\ref{h1head}

\end{document}

and the log file shows:
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `eq1' on input line 12.

Is this any possibility to get the unused label details as separate output file, like, let's assume that the output file name may be as crossrefcheck.txt and it should contains as:
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `eq1' on input line 12.

Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `tab1' on input line 13.

Please advise

You could try something like the following. But be aware that the package hasn't been updated in last 11 years, and e.g. breaks the starred versions of the reference commands (which with hyperref create references without links).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\makeatletter
\newwrite\refcheckwarnings
\immediate\openout\refcheckwarnings{\jobname.rfc} % or some other extension
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/@warning@rc@/before}{\protected@write\refcheckwarnings{}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{H1 Head}\label{h1head}

\lipsum[1]\label{blub}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

Test for cross-ref\ref{h1head}
\ref*{eq1}
\end{document}


Thanks, this works beautifully, I too noticed that this package was not updated so many years, kindly suggest is there alternative updated package available for this \label and \ref validation purpose
